# Why Miller–Rabin instead of Fermat primality test?

Tags: algorithms, primes

From the proof of [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test), if a number passes the [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), it must also pass the Miller-Rabin test with the same base $a$ (a variable in the proof). And the computation complexity is the same.

The following is from the [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test):

> While Carmichael numbers are substantially rarer than prime
>   numbers,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test) there are enough of them that Fermat's primality test is
>   often not used in the above form. Instead, **other more powerful
>   extensions** of the Fermat test, such as Baillie-PSW, Miller-Rabin, and
>   Solovay-Strassen are more commonly used.

What is the benefit of Miller-Rabin and why it is said to be more powerful than the Fermat primality test?

Answer (score 7):

The Rabin-Miller algorithm also tests, given a number $n$, whether $Z_n$ has a nontrivial root of Unity.

Carmichael numbers pass the Fermat test (for every basis $a$), but for every Carmichael number $n$, there exist many numbers $a$ such that the test for unity roots fails on $a$ (that is, the sequence $a,2a,...,2^ra$ eventually displays a nontrivial root of unity).

Thus, we have the following:

For Fermat's test, if a composite number $n$ is not Carmichael, then the probability that the test will detect compositeness is at least $1/2$. However, the test will fail all Carmichael numbers.

For the Rabin-Miller test, every composite number will be detected with probability at least $1/2$. This means that the correctness probability is independent of the input (there are no "hard" inputs). This is what makes this algorithm stronger.

Comment: Do you means Carmichael number n can success on Fermat's test but failed on Rabin-Miller using the same base `a`?

Comment: Carmichael numbers pass Fermat's test for every $a$, but for some $a$'s it will fail the Rabin-Miller test (specifically, the root of Unity test).

Comment: But Carmichael will not pass Fermat's test for every $a$, correct? For example the first Carmichael number 561=3*11*17 will not pass Fermat's test for $a$ = 3 or 11 or 17.

Comment: When we say "pass" we mean that they will *not* be detected as composite numbers. Thus, Carmichael numbers will pass the test for every $a$. I think we mean the same thing. In this example, 561 will pass Fermat's test for every number $a$.

Comment: The point of the "more complex" tests is that the fraction of bases which lie (say the number is perhaps prime, when it isn't) has a guaranteed limit less than 1. I.e., in Miller-Rabin it can be shown that at most 1/4 lie (IIRC, and the bound is quite pessimistic).

Comment: @Shaull, We mean the same thing when we say “pass“. 561 will not pass using $a$=3 for Fermat's testing. '3^560 mod 561 = 375'

Comment: This is because $(561,3)=3$.  A Carmichael number is one that satifies the equation $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \mod n$ whenever $(a,n)=1$.

Comment: @Shaull: Fermat with a Carmichael number x passes for every number a, except for divisors of x. So finding an a that proves x is composite, we just have to find a divisor of x. Well, if we found a divisor then we don't need Fermat anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your statement is the opposite of what happens.  Passing the Miller-Rabin test for a given base means it will pass the Fermat test for the same base.  In contrast, there are many composites that will pass the Fermat test for a given base but will fail the Miller-Rabin test for the same base.

See, for example, the paper by Pomerance / Selfridge / Wagstaff in the Wikipedia Miller-Rabin page:

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper25.pdf

where we see a diagram on page 2 showing the Euler pseudoprimes being a subset of the Fermat pseudoprimes, and the strong pseudoprimes being a subset of those.  The Solovay-Strassen test is therefore more discerning than the Fermat test, and the Miller-Rabin test more than either.  They both avoid the critical problem of Carmichael numbers.  They have essentially the same performance, so we prefer to use the Miller-Rabin test.

Answer (score 0):

It should be obvious that Miller-Rabin is better than Fermat.

With the Fermat test, we check whether $a^{p-1}$ = 1 (modulo p).

With the Miller-Rabin test, to calculate $a^{p-1}$ we find k and odd s such that $p-1 = s·2^k$. Then we calculate $a^s$ modulo p, and calculate k times the square modulo p. That's a pretty obvious way to calculate $a^{p-1}$.

Again, if the result is not 1 (modulo p) then p is composite. But if the result *is* 1 modulo p, then we check whether we got that 1 by squaring an intermediate result that wasn't +1 or -1, and in that case x is also proven composite.

So we do exactly the same amount of work, but there are more ways to prove that x is composite.